# Making file metadata on a filesystem not supporting it

Tags: linux, permissions, filesystems

I have here a storage without supporting the most important metadatas (permissions, owners, etc).

I think, it would help a lot if I could somehow solve that I inject some type of metadata in the system from an external source. Last time as I have seen some similar, that was the today really ancient [umsdos](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/UMSDOS-HOWTO-6.html) filesystem, some decades ago. It stored the posix ownership and permissions info in small database files in all directories of a fat16 filesystem.

This time I have no word to change the storage. Also I have no influence over the permission flags it gives. But I would want to emulate them locally.

Is it somehow possible in Linux?

Comment: `a storage` what sort of storage? what filesystem does it use?

Comment: Do the files have to go directly into this storage? Can you use a squashfs filesystem (or any file with a filesystem formatted into it, really) instead for putting the files in, and then put the filesystem file into storage?

Comment: @JaromandaX In my current case, it uses 9pfs of a qemu. That qemu runs on an android without root, thus it can not change file ownership. That is yet in planning phase, so nothing works and I am collecting my ideas, how to make it working. Another case what I have often found, that I had a davfs or an sshfs mount, also where I could not change file ownership and permissions (either because protocol limitations or in the lack of root). Third case was as I tried to boot an ntfs filesystem with a linux kernel, that was a home experiment (most posix features are supported by ntfs not everything).

Comment: @muru Yes it would be important on performance reason.  Squasfs or any loop-based solutions are not very useful in this sense (still might qualify as an answer but not for me).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The POSIX overlay filesystem](https://inai.de/projects/posixovl/) might solve your problem — it’s a FUSE-based overlay capable of adding POSIX metadata to non-POSIX file systems.

Its last official release dates back to 2018 but [its source repo](https://codeberg.org/jengelh/posixovl) is still being updated.